# How to create a Django form from foreign key relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to create a multiple choice question form where all choices where the foreign key points to that question are displayed as checkboxes.

From similar questions, I have gathered that subclassing `ModelForms` might be the way to do this. But I couldn't figure out how to pass the specific `question_id` to the `ModelForm`.

Currently, I am trying the following:

from `model.py`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choice
```

So in `forms.py`, I've tried to create such a form:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        question_id = kwargs.pop('question')
        self.fields['checkboxes'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
             queryset = Choice.objects.filter(question = question_id))
```

In `views.py`, I create a `QuestionForm`, passing the `question_id` as constructor argument.
But I keep getting a `NameError "name 'question_id' is not defined` in QuestionForm where the MOdelChoiceField is constructed.

Comment: Does it help if you move `question_id = ...` above the `super` call, so it gets popped first?

Comment: Try with   Choice.objects.filter(question__id = question_id)  .

Comment: Nope, both didn't help... funnily, if I assign the result of Choice.objects.filter(question__id = question_id) to a local variable called "choices" and then pass queryset=choices, I get the NameError for 'choices' no being defined...

Comment: You should get a TypeError `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'question'`unless you have made the change suggested by Daniel. But if you've moved the pop to the top of __init__ there isn't anything wrong with your code as far as I can see. Is your code above a simplified version of your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) talk about the Meta class:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

does it help?